# Relation QGIS: get_feature

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, relation

I have 2 layers (1 polygon / 1 no-geometry (aType)). I have a relation between them.

As we know, we can display 1 value from the related layer via layer property -> Attributes Form.
[image: Relation]

In the widget type Relation Reference we can select "Display expression" (in my case dispName).

I want to display the dispName as a Simple Label. If I now select the aType as the value for the Label, the display expression is not shown.

How can I have the label of the related field as a simple label?